# $^t$, $^\dagger$, $^*$, $^H$, $^⊤$, and $^T$ : Which is which, and what do each mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I think this question's answer(s) will be of profound use to the future generation of human beings who happen to stumble upon the website *math.stackexchange.com*.

---

What are the differences between $^t$, $^\dagger$, $^*$, $^H$, and $^T$. Further, to which is which associated, and are there some cases where one is used for both?

---

I'd like to see definitions for each group of superscript symbols and how $T$ the transformation and $A$ the matrix are related. I feel it would be good to have this as an answer here for all eyes to see.

Comment: I thing generally $t$ and $T$ are for transpose, $*$ and $H$ are for the conjugate transpose or adjoint, and the dagger for the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: Is what you're saying is that $A^*$ and $T^*$ convey the same information?

Comment: Don't forget ${}^t A$.

Answer (score 8):

When $A$ is a matrix,

- $A^t$ and $A^T$ stand for the [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)
- $A^*$ (and possibly $A^H$, but I don't remember seeing it used this way) stand for [Hermitian adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint). The Wikipedia article says that $\dagger$ is also used for this purpose, by the kind of people who say bra and ket.
- $A^\dagger$ stands for the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)

Comment: I have seen people using $A^{*}$ for complex conjugate of $A$ and $A^{\dagger}$ for Hermitian adjoint. They even appear in same article. What is what is usually clear in the context.

Comment: For pseudoinverse, $A^\dagger$ was popular in earlier linear algebra literature, but $A^+$ seems to be more widespread in recent years. Also, some physicists seem to use $A^\dagger$ for Hermitian adjoint. Transposes can be denoted by $A^T$ (most common), $A^t,\,A^\top$ and $\phantom{}^tA$.

Comment: ... and $A^\prime$. (A habit initiated by Matlab-programmers?)

Comment: You really want $*$ for the adjoint, because if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space, then $B(H)$ is a $C^*$-algebra where the star operation is *precisely* "take the adjoint".

Answer (score 3):

If you use $A^\sf T$ and $A^\sf H$ respectively for the transpose and Hermitian conjugate of $A$ (which I prefer), then you are free to use $t,T,H,$ and * for other things, which is useful. The notation $A^+$ for the pseudo-inverse is aesthetically in line with this and more modern than $A^\dagger$.