# What does the "$\top\,$" in "$\,y = [x,u,v,y]^{\top}\,$" mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, notation

There is a diffrential equation which takes the form:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,t) $$

$$y = [x,u,v,y]^{\top}$$

What does the superscript of $\top$ in this case mean?

Comment: Means transpose, that is, $y$ is a $4$-th dimensional column vector.

Comment: T means transpose, which in simplest form means going from horizontal to vertical.  For matrices it means flipping horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$^t$, $^\dagger$, $^*$, $^H$, $^⊤$, and $^T$ : Which is which, and what do each mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410688/t-dagger-h-%e2%8a%a4-and-t-which-is-which-and-what-do-each)

Comment: It is an abuse of notation to use $y$ to mean both a vector and one of its components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, it stands for "[transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)":
$$\begin{bmatrix} x & u & v & y \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ u \\ v \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$